# Asterisk shared data between two channels in a call

Tags: java, asterisk, agi

I want to pass some message between two communicating channels in call, My requirement is two java applications will act as two different users in a call, There should be some message that can be shared only between two channels in specific call, so that if one application is going to play something it can send message saying that you record now and vice-verse. I will be thankful if somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMI to watch for UserA trying to share data, and then set it on UserB's channel.

Background to this...

Sounds like a similar problem that I had. With two users in a call, I wanted user A to start recording the call. I wanted the recording to start on User B's channel so that if the call was transfer, that channel was not destroyed and the recording would continue. Simply calling MixMonitor starts the recording on the channel that calls MixMonitor which would be UserA's channel.

I wrote a small application that monitors UserA and listens for a UserEvent from UserA (see 'core show application UserEvent') and then start Mixmonitor on UserB's channel. It also has to keep track of channels so that it knows which channel belongs to UserB.